# Railgun Ruby - is there a documentation?

Tags: ruby

I finally found Railgun Ruby on the web and installed it.

But I cannot find any documentations.

Does anyone have played around with it? Does anyone still have a good documentation about it?

I'd like to have a look at what it can do.

Thanks.

Yours, Joern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like it. The project appears dead -- links to it's homepage on Rubyforge go nowhere, and there's only a [few casual mentions of it](http://oreilly.com/pub/a/ruby/2007/12/18/creating-games-in-ruby-part-2.html?page=3) around the internet (usually with associated chatter about [Rubygame](http://rubygame.org/) and some naysayers asserting that Ruby isn't suitable for game development -- YMMV).

I wouldn't recommend using a library in this state. Rubygame looks, at least superficially, like a much more viable product than Railgun.

Comment: rubygame is for 2d only... I know ruby won't be the best for 3d, but I wanted to play around a little, test some ideas for game engines

Comment: Ah I didn't realize that you wanted 3D specifically -- you can probably find some generic OpenGL bindings out there. I don't see why Ruby would be inherently unsuitable (that was just hearsay) except perhaps in a lack of robust framework support for games.

Answer (score 2):

You may checkout ruby Game libraries at ruby-toolbox.
https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/game_libraries
(13 projects)

There is list of languages bindings: http://freegamedev.net/wiki/index.php/Free,_cross-platform,_real-time_3D_engines#Native_and_binded_languages_support

also you may search "3D Game engine with Ruby binding ?" at ruby-forum.com/topic/92822
and "Velocity Reviews > Newsgroups > Programming > Ruby > Ruby 3D" at velocityreviews dot c0m

sorry, some information not so fresh